# SDL error in Xcode

Tags: xcode, macos, sdl

I was trying to use SDL framework for jpg loading of opengl texture, but when i try to build i got this message:

```
   ld: warning: in /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk/Library/Frameworks//SDL.framework/SDL, missing required architecture ppc in file
```

What can i do to made SDL work in i386?
Have to download the source code and then make the file, or there is one already for i386?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning message says the version of the SDL framework on your machine is Intel-only, but you are building a universal (Intel and PowerPC) SDL application. The main Mac version of SDL 1.2.15 dropped PowerPC support. The simplest solution is to go to the SDL site and download the version of the SDL libraries that has support for PowerPC and Mac OS X 10.4.

Another solution is to modify the Architectures build setting in your project and tell Xcode to build for Intel only.

Comment: thanks but thats the problem Mark I'm building in i386 not ppc and i have the 1.2.15 that should be working in my mac. ow can i modify to build for intel only?

Comment: Verify that you have the universal version of SDL installed. In the Finder go into the SDL.framework folder and find the SDL file, which should appear in the Finder as a Unix executable. Select that file and choose File > Get Info in the Finder, which will tell you if you have a universal version or an Intel-only version. Also verify that your Architectures build setting is not set to Universal for both the Debug and Release configurations.